# AdWords - conversions data not showing in campaign report

Tags: google-ads-api

In the campaign I am running, I can see conversion data in Tools/Conversions tab, but I can´t see any data for conversions in Campaign or Ad or Keyword report.

Do you know what is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say.  Here's my guess... Conversions are reported on the day the click occurred, not the date of the conversion.  So expand your date range and make sure you've added the Conversions or Converted Clicks column (see the "Columns" drop down from the campaign tab).